# Processing Async Calls in ActionBlock

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am having issues with processing Async lambda in ActionBlock.

```
var state = new ConcurrentBag<UsersData>();
var getData = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<int>>(async (userIdsBatch) =>
{
    var query = _queryBuilder.GetQuery(userIdsBatch);
    string response = await _handler.GetResponseAsync(query).ConfigureAwait(false);
    UsersData userData = new Parser().GetUserData(response);
    state.Add(userData);
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _MAX_DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM // 1
});


foreach (IEnumerable<int> userIdsBatch in GetUserBatches(userIds, 10))
{
    getData.Post(userIdsBatch);
}

getData.Complete();

await getData.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);

// merge the states for different batches synchronously.
```

The ActionBlock is exiting before completion of the async call within it. Few Tasks that were produced are thrown away, not all of them are completed.

Is there a way to wait for all the tasks to complete before the synchronously merging the results?

Comment: Remove all those `ConfigureAwait()` calls, they aren't needed. There's nothing wrong with `ActionBlock` either, it will just work with async lambdas. That *ConcurrenBag* though isn't needed at all. If you want to produce results, use a TransformBlock instead of an ActionBlock and either read its output, or redirect it to a BufferBlock

Comment: Can't reproduce that behavior, is `GetResponseAsync`, or any other line in the block, throwing? That would cause your block to fault and ignore whatever remains in its input buffer.

Comment: nope, none of the lines are throwing any exceptions. This only happens when the `GetResponseAsync` call takes longer to execute. When the batch size is reduced to 5 userIds everything works as expected.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks, I will checkout `TransformBlock`.

Comment: @kiran6: Please post a [minimal example that illustrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).